# How do I parse and rebuild a URL in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, url, parameters

I'm devloping a C#/ASP.Net app and I'm trying to find a means of breaking down a URL into its component parts, then swapping out, or deleting these parts and creating a new URL.

For example if I have the following URL:

- https://www.site.com/page.aspx?parm1=value1&parm2=value2

I'd like to split the URL down into:

- Protocol (http, https, ftp, etc)
- Domain (www.site.com)
- Page (page.aspx)
- URL parameters (parm1 = value1, parm2 = value2)

Once the URL is split down I'd like to manipulate each of the parts, for example:

- add or remove parameters
- change the value of parameters
- change the page from page.aspx to page2.aspx

Then once I'm done create a new URL ready for use with the above changes.

I've checked out the MSDN documentation etc and can't find a utility class in .Net to take care of this. Any ideas?

Cheers,
Steve

Answer (score 5):

The framework comes with the [UriBuilder class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) for this purpose.

It has get/set properties for the things you need:

- Protocol: [Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.scheme.aspx) property
- Domain: [Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.host.aspx) property
- Page: [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.path.aspx) property (will give you whole path, you might need to do some processing here).
- Parameters: [Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.query.aspx) property (exposed as a string, you might need to do some processing on the string your self).

When you are done manipulating the UriBuilder, use the Uri property to get the result as a Uri object, or just ToString() if you just need the URL as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Start by using UriBuilder (see driis's answer).

To parse the Query property use:

```
NameValueCollection q=HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
```

You actually get an HttpValueCollection (internal) - so when you later call q.ToString() you'll get an url encoded query string back.

Since the class is internal you need to call

```
NameValueCollection q=HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("");
```

if you want to build the query string from scratch.